# With helm template file conditionally set a variables used throughout template file

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I want to conditionally set a 'go' variable at the top of my helm template file then use it later in the template file. Here is what I tried that doesn't work:

At the top of my template file, I do the following:

```
{{- if eq $.Values.kafka.create true -}}
{{- $kafka_port := 9094 -}}
{{- else -}}
{{- $kafka_port := $.Values.kafka.port -}} 
{{- end }}
```

But when I attempt to do "helm install" I get a parse error where I use $kafka_port later in the template file. The specific error is:

Error: parse error at (tombolo/templates/tom-node-launch.yaml:89): undefined variable "$kafka_port"

Answer (score 2):

Define the variable in the outer block:

```
{{- $kafka_port := 9094 -}}
{{- if eq $.Values.kafka.create false -}}
{{- $kafka_port = $.Values.kafka.port -}} 
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is pretty short and may well be ok for your use case.

But as a general rule : when you start writing code in your templates, it could also be an indication that you should write code in the controller part (the go code) :

```
type KafkaCfg struct {
    port   int
    create bool
}

const kafkaCreationPort = 9094

func (c KafkaCfg) Port() int {
    if c.create {
        return kafkaCreationPort
    }
    return c.port
}


func someWhereElse() {
    var data struct {
        Values struct {
            Kafka KafkaCfg
        }
    }

    data.Values.Kafka.create = true
    helmTemplate.Execute(w, data)
}

// in your template :

{{ .Values.Kafka.Port }} {{ /* <- will call the .Port() method */ }}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/6pNHY0kcegp

Answer (score 0):

The Go `text/template` language (as distinct from the Go programming language itself) doesn't have global variables.

The thing you can do is to write a [helper template](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/), typically in `templates/_helpers.tpl`, that generates this fragment:

```
{{- define "kafka.port" -}}
{{- if .Values.kafka.create -}}
9094
{{- else -}}
{{- .Values.kafka.port -}}
{{- end -}}
```

This template *outputs* the port number when called; its single parameter should be the standard [top-level Helm object](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/).

```yaml
- name: KAFKA_PORT
  value: {{ include "kafka.port" . | quote }}
```

Or, if in a specific context, you happen to need it as a variable, you can include it there (using the [Helm `include` extension](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#the-include-function) to capture the called template's output as a string); but it will be limited to its specific template or file.

```yaml
{{- $kafkaPort := include "kafka.port" . }}
- name: KAFKA_PORT
  value: {{ quote $kafkaPort }}
- name: KAFKA_BROKER_URL
  value: kafka://{{ include "kafka.name" . }}:{{ $kafkaPort }}
```